# Обработка изменения вывода аудио у текущего звонка

Tags: java, android

Требуется отслеживать изменения вывода аудио для текущего звонка (например динамики, громкая связь, блютуз), не могу понять какой ресивер за это отвечает.

Сама задача состоит в том, чтобы следить за текущим звонком, и если вывод был переключен на что либо кроме блютуза то завершать звонок.